# Can I pass a string in angularJs directive template?

Tags: html, angularjs

I am new to angularJS. Here is my sample code :

```
app.directive("w3TestDirective", function() {
        return {
            template :  '<ul>'+
                        '<div ng-repeat="rows in roleMenulistByID">'+
                        '<li>{{rows.route_alias_name}}</li>'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '</ul>'
        };
    });
```

My question is can I send the template data as an angular string? Say,

```
$scope.string = '<ul>'+
                '<div ng-repeat="rows in roleMenulistByID">'+
                '<li>{{rows.route_alias_name}}</li>'+
                '</div>'+
                '</ul>';
```

how can I achieve that? if I say

```
template : $scope.string
```

It shows an error. Please help & thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. Please post what you're trying to achieve instead of asking about the solution.

Comment: "$scope is not defined" this is the error. So I have to define it in the directive somehow. I am just asking for the proper way :)

Comment: That's what I'm trying to tell you. You have a problem, you think passing the template as a string is the solution. It might not be the solution at all, in which case trying to troubleshoot it would be pointless. See [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: That was interesting man !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass `template` string via corresponding attribute and use `function` at directive declaration as value of `template` property:

```js
angular.module('app', []).directive('test', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template: function(el, attrs) {
      return attrs.template;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-init='items=[1,2,3]'>
  <test template='<p ng-repeat="x in items">{{x}}</p>'><test>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't answer my question, though nice idea !

Comment: @SouravBhowmik, look at updated answer, where you will have exactly desired behavior

Comment: technically you answered my question, so I will accept it as the right answer. But can you help me furhtermore? :)

Comment: There is a problem in this solution though, angular default directives ng-repeat doesn't work if I pass it via the template string.

Comment: @SouravBhowmik, for me it works, as you can see at updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Slava !